# ASPX page within a .aspx page with iframe throws 500.23 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iframe, iis-7.5

I'm trying to embed a `ChartModule.aspx` page within a `Default.aspx` page using an `iframe`.

The ChartModule has a button event which updates a chart. The ChartModule has its own `ChartsModule.cs`.

I'm getting this error:

> HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been
>   detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.Most
>   likely causes:
>
> •This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers
>   section.  Things you can try: •Migrate the configuration to the
>   system.webServer/handlers section. You can do so manually or by using
>   AppCmd from the command line. For example, from the IIS Express
>   install directory, run appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/".
>   Using AppCmd to migrate your application will enable it to work in
>   Integrated mode. It will continue to work in Classic mode and on
>   previous versions of IIS. •If you are certain that it is OK to ignore
>   this error, it can be disabled by setting
>   system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to
>   false. •Alternatively, switch the application to a Classic mode
>   application pool. For example, from the IIS Express install directory,
>   run appcmd set app "Default Web Site/"
>   /applicationPool:"Clr4ClassicAppPool". Only do this if you are unable
>   to migrate your application.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module    ConfigurationValidationModule 
>   Notification    BeginRequest  Handler
>   PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0  Error Code    0x80070032  Requested
>   URL    http://localhost:4161/Default.aspx  Physical Path
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\singhm\Desktop\Temp\Trial2\Trial2\Default.aspx  Logon Method 
>   Not yet determined  Logon User    Not yet determined  Request Tracing
>   Directory

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not answer your question directly, here is a thought:

If you have the option, consider turning `ChartModule.aspx` into a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) (`ascx`), which acts just like another "page" (same lifecycle, its own codebehind file, etc) but integrates more cleanly into an existing `aspx` page. The above link should be a good introduction to creating and using UserControls.

Answer (score 1):

The error message contains a clue to the solution:

> setting `system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration` to false

So make sure the following is present in your `web.config`:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

For example:

```
<configuration>

  <!-- your existing settings -->

  <system.webServer>

    <!-- Add this to here.... -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IIS 7 and ASP.NET are quite helpful these days with regard to to error messages and hints contained therein so you should take the time to read them.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using a usercontrol page instead of iframes in asp.net this way you can bind that usercontrol by doing

```
public override DataBind()
```

in that you can pass anything into that usercontrol page like refresh data, load certain data, etc..